# Dummy interface is not reachable from other system through ping

Tags: networking, kernel, ping, packet

I connected two Debian 10 systems with a direct link.

On one of them I defined a dummy interface and on the other I gave a static route to access it. I see the traffic from the sender on the interface, but I don't see the traffic on the opposite system, and no response is received.

Is it possible that the traffic was dropped by the opposite system?

```
sudo ip link add lo1 type dummy
sudo ip link set dev lo1 up
sudo ip addr add 13.13.13.13/32 dev lo1
```

```
pc2~$ ip addr show lo1
   63: lo1: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ae:e2:d8:95:2b:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 13.13.13.13/32 brd 13.13.13.13 scope global lo1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ace2:d8ff:fe95:2bae/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


pc2~$ sudo sysctl -p
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies: No such file or directory
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
kernel.printk = 1 4 1 7
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 2
```

and another system:

```
sudo ip route add 13.13.13.13/32 via 20.20.20.2

pc1~$ ip addr show port25
31: port25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:f8:f8:76:53:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 20.20.20.1/24 brd 20.20.20.255 scope global port25
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6f8:f8ff:fe76:5359/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

pc1(20.20.20.1)-------(20.20.20.2)pc2(lo2:13.13.13.13/32)

```
pc1~$ sudo tcpdump -ni port25 icmp

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on port25, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes




22:54:42.098033 IP 20.20.20.1 > 13.13.13.13: ICMP echo request, id 3321, seq 0, length 64
22:54:43.107142 IP 20.20.20.1 > 13.13.13.13: ICMP echo request, id 3321, seq 1, length 64
22:54:44.117137 IP 20.20.20.1 > 13.13.13.13: ICMP echo request, id 3321, seq 2, length 64
22:54:45.127138 IP 20.20.20.1 > 13.13.13.13: ICMP echo request, id 3321, seq 3, length 64
22:54:46.137143 IP 20.20.20.1 > 13.13.13.13: ICMP echo request, id 3321, seq 4, length 64
```

```
pc2:~$ sudo tcpdump -ni port25 icmp
Password: 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on port25, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
```

```
pc1~$ ip route
default nhid 16 via 192.168.60.2 dev enp0 proto 196 metric 20 
13.13.13.13 nhid 79 via 20.20.20.2 dev port25 proto 196 metric 20 
20.20.20.0/24 dev port25 proto kernel scope link src 20.20.20.1 
50.50.60.60 nhid 16 via 192.168.60.2 dev enp0 proto 196 metric 20 
192.168.60.0/24 dev enp0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.60.75 
192.168.121.0/24 dev port2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.121.37 linkdown
```

```
pc2~$ ip route
default nhid 26 via 192.168.60.2 dev enp0 proto 196 metric 20 
20.20.20.0/24 dev port25 proto kernel scope link src 20.20.20.2 
192.168.22.0/24 dev port1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.22.156 
192.168.60.0/24 dev enp0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.60.76 
zharf-switch:~$
```

Comment: Can you install Wireshark on your pc2? Then you can see the packets on your MICROSOFT-CORP-MSN-AS-BLOCK-interface (20.20.20.2) and separately on your Xerox interface (13.13.13.13). Then you will know where the packets are dropped.

Comment: How exactly do you detect that you "don't see the traffic on the opposite system". Show settings/command and output of Wireshark or tcpdump (or similar) on both interfaces.

Comment: Requested details added.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to enable IP forwarding on the system that you want to forward packets between interfaces. Assuming you use Linux, it is disabled by default.

Citing https://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/:

Check the setting with `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`

Change it with `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Depending on your distribution there are different ways to make this setting permanent.

Comment: Tnx, but this option is enabled: sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Comment: @user8178737 Add this information to the question.